# Requirements for collection class to be used with LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, sharepoint, ienumerable

I always thought that enough requirement that class should satisfy to be able to use `Where()` with it is to implement `IEnumerable`.

But today a friend of mine asked me a question, why he cannot apply `Where()` to the object of [SPUserCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spusercollection.aspx) class (it is from Sharepoint). Since this class is derived from [SPBaseCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasecollection.aspx) which implements `IEnumerable` - I expected everything should be fine. But it is not.

Any ideas, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LINQ extension methods are defined over `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IEnumerable`.  For example, see the [`Where<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
)
```

To mitigate this issue, the LINQ [`Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) extension method turns an `IEnumerable` into an `IEnumerable<T>` that can then be used with the normal LINQ functions.

In the example below, you can't do `e.Where(...)`, but you can `Cast` it and then use `Where`.

```
int[] xs = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
IEnumerable e = xs;
var odds = e.Cast<int>().Where(x => x % 2 == 1);
```

Unfortunately, this needs to be used a lot when dealing with pre-generics APIs in the .NET BCL.

Comment: Oh, I knew that it is something obvious ;-) Thank you.

Comment: Yes, in some unknown reason I thought that LINQ automatically does cast for non-generic collections.

Comment: @zerkms Yeah I get surprised every time IntelliSense pops-up without the extension methods.  Good thing they included `Cast` in the shipping libraries!